# How to pass the identity of the caller Script to the external Script Library?

Tags: applescript

How to **best** pass the identity of the caller Script to the external Script Library?

I have found a way to do this successfully ... however the question then becomes "Is it the **best** way?"

In the **external** Script Library, I have:

```
property pCallerScript : 0

on libPassCaller(theCallerScript)

    set pCallerScript to theCallerScript

end libPassCaller
```

followed later in this Library, for example:

```
set topmostError to pCallerScript's gTerminateThisScript & return & return & localError
```

I set all this up via the following code in my Calling Script:

```
property pExternalLib : ""
set pExternalLib to load script file pExternalScriptFile

property passCaller : me
pExternalLib's libPassCaller(passCaller)
```

So, is this the very best way?

Comment: Is there a particular reason the external library needs to use the caller?  Sounds like a good way to get some circular references.

Comment: Why don't you use the convenient `use` syntax rather than old-fashioned `load script`?

Comment: What is your larger goal here? Can you tell us what you're trying to accomplish; *why* you want to do this?

Comment: I am simply trying to learn about external libraries and how to best do things. 

In total honesty, I am unable to convince myself that they are really necessary versus the simple use of global Parms. 

I think it’s a meaningful learning exercise nonetheless.

Comment: Great answer, John. I believe experimentation is the greatest way to learn, and this includes experimenting with things that might have no practical use. You can probably improve the implementation by making use of the `parent` property, and by using _script objects_. Additional properties to set for a script and a script library that can have some usefulness, but can also be just decoration, are `name`, `id` (like a bundle identifier, even though it's not a bundle), and `key`. Unlike `parent`, functionally, these do nothing, but can provide a core set of data to identify a script.

Comment: Oh how I would love to Be able to tell a user put my Library anywhere and it’ll do the job regardless. In short, total location independence. Even if my Library used an external Library of mine.